# What is the difference between salmon/fish oil for a cat and a human?

Tags: cats, health, medicines

One of my cats is suffering from a nasty bought of dry skin. He's a new adoptee, and is quite overweight. I am feeding him a healthy amount of wet food, and although he has access to free feeding of dry, does not seem to participate in the munching of the crunches.

I noticed the dry skin fairly soon after adopting him, but have tried to give him time to adjust to his new diet. The problem hasn't resolved itself yet, so my next step is to try some salmon oil or fish oil. I have consulted a vet on this.

Only, the oils marketed to pet owners are incredibly overpriced compared to the capsules marketed to humans. I want to buy the cheaper option, because it irks me that the cat version is $10 or more simply because it has "for cats" on the label.

Are they truly equal? If I buy the human salmon oil, can I just pop it open onto his wet food and be done with it, or is there ingredients (or lack of ingredients) that make the cat salmon oil special?

(picture of his disarrayed lazy self: [image])

Comment: Related question [Can I give my cat human medicine?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/726) .

Comment: I altered the title of your question, as shopping questions are out of scope here, I believe the new title better clarifies what your expressed in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference except the price, as far as I know, because there should be no added ingredients. I noticed the same thing when I was looking for cod liver oil capsules for my dog - so I have been giving him ones aimed at humans for 2 years now.

Comment: Sorry - the ingredients were exactly the same - i.e. cod liver oil, which I took to mean that they were in fact the same!