# What is the best way to treat feline ringworm?

Tags: cats, medicines

Our Persian mixed cat has feline ringworm. It doesn't seem to bother her, but treatment appears to be long & difficult.

I understand it is caused by the same fungus that causes athletes foot, so I wonder if creams & sprays available for humans could be used safely on a cat.

Comment: Related question [Can I give my cat human medicine?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/726)

Answer (score 3):

No.  Don't ever use human medication unless advised to do so by a vet.

The reason treatment for cats can be difficult is because cats have so few options.  Cats are susceptible to all sorts of poisons that are perfectly safe for humans and this rules out a lot of options from human medical science.

There are too many horror stories of cats poisoned by their well-meaning owners.  Even [shampoos](http://messybeast.com/teatree.htm) can be fatal to cats due to the plant extracts they contain.

Comment: I like this answer, but could you add a reference for the cats being poisoned by plant extracts in shampoo, I have not heard of this before.

Comment: Just for clarity, don't ever use human medication on cats *except on the advice of your vet*. There are a few situations where a vet will recommend human medicine in tiny doses, but I doubt that ringworm is one of those situations. And yes, treatment does tend to be for a long time, so make sure you're consistent with the prescribed medication.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, I can't find the original link that talked about use of human shampoo on cats, right now, but (and this is kind of worrying) there are a heap of resources on cat shampoos killing cats by using the same ingredient.  I haven't seen much tea tree shampoo for humans in California.  In the UK many brands taint almost their whole product lines with that or other terpene sources because they're natural and they smell nice.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I asked a question addressing this concern http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/is-it-safe-to-use-topical-products-containing-tea-tree-oil-on-my-cat