# Can I treat a kitten with medicine (Amoxicillin) that I already have at home?

Tags: cats, medicines

Can I use amoxicillin to treat a kitten who is approximately 10 weeks old?

He appears to be congested, maybe has a sinus infection.

If it's OK to do this:

- What is the dosage?
- How often can I give it to him?
- What is the length of time I should be giving it to him?

I do not have money for a Vet, so taking him there is not an option for me.

Comment: Where are you located? We have a question about getting help for your animal if you cannot afford the treatments: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 6):

The only thing you can and should do is to take the kitten to a vet as soon as possible.

Never give a pet medication unless it is prescribed by a vet and it is for the specific animal and for the illness it is prescribed for. Giving a kitten antibiotics can be very dangerous it will often give the kitten diarrhoea which will often lead to dehydration and the kitten might die.

It is dangerous to medicate kittens for the reasons I have mentioned before so if you do this be sure the kitten is well hydrated by giving wet food and having water for your cat at all times.

Comment: Good answer, I did remove your dosage recommendation as there are several variables and what you had entered may not be correct.  There is more info at [Amoxicillin dosage and length of treatment for cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/amoxicillin-dosage-and-length-of-treatment-for-cat)