# Can I use vitamin pills meant for humans in home-cooked meals for my cats?

Tags: cats, diet, safety

I am researching on home-cooked meals for my cats and all the articles I've came across emphasize the importance of adding additional vitamin supplements into the meal but they did not mentioned specifically to get vitamins for pets.

Does this mean I can get any good ol' vitamin pills from pharmacies given that they are pure and do not have additional ingredients added to them?

The vitamins mentioned are Taurine, Vitamin B, Vitamin E.

Related but more on medicine instead of vitamin: [Can I give my cat human medicine?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/726/can-i-give-my-cat-human-medicine)

Comment: Related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17546/supplements-for-kitten-being-fed-on-home-cooked-food

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not as human grade vitamins are not regulated, there was a study done in my province where they took a bunch of different brand supplements and calculated the amount of the product is in each pill - they were always off and some were significantly lower than the amount said on the bottle  (ex. 200mg vitamin A capsule only contained 5mg of vitamin A).

Pet supplements you get at veterinary hospitals ARE regulated and you will get what it says on the bottle.
[Hilary's blend](http://www.completeandbalancedforcats.com/) has the vitamin/mineral mix needed for her recipes, this is who we recommend for owners that want to make their pets food.

Answer (score 4):

Different animals have different physiologies.  What's safe for humans isn't necessarily safe for animals.  Even those that are safe may only be safe at smaller dosages, or may have no effect at all.  Many animals, for example, are able to produce their own Vitamin C.

Likewise, the safe delivery mechanisms might differ.

Please check with a very before you try anything.  You may end up with an expensive vets bill and a sick animal to look after or worse.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, in most cases vitamins are non-toxic so there is no risk of an overdose.

Vitamins such as taurine, B1 (thiamin) and E are all common nutrients found in abundance in animal flesh and it is not possible to take too much of them.

There is no difference between "pet" vitamins and "human" vitamins, other than marketing. The vendors that supply such vitamins get them from exactly the same sources.

Comment: A quick google search finds several vitamins that can be a problem See [What OTC vitamins or supplements that people take are toxic to cats?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15641)

Comment: @JamesJenkins I did not say ALL vitamins. I said TAURINE, B1 and E are safe for cats.

Comment: "in most cases vitamins are non-toxic so there is no risk of an overdose."

Comment: @JamesJenkins Most is not all. There are only a few common vitamins that are toxic to cats in large doses and the OP did not specify any of those.

Comment: This is plainly wrong in a variety of ways and dangerously so.  Not to be a jerk about it, but misinformation like this endangers the health and life of innocent pets.