# Home remedy for suspected fever in cat

Tags: cats, health, ears-nose-throat

My cat’s head is warmer than usual. Nose and paw pads are hot pink, it has been this way for 4 hours. Breathing is faster than normal, occasionally she breathes very fast just like after playtime but was she previously idle. Other than that she seems fine. She still plays, eats, grooms and asks for pets, no sign of fatigue. I have been wiping her body with a damp towel every 30 minutes in case she does have a fever. I havent seen her drink water today but she eats wet food and fish often.

I can't go to the vets because my country is in emergency 1 month lockdown. They closed most vet offices and forbid everyone from leaving their street. 2 people already got fined for taking their dying cat to the vets and the cats didnt make it. I don’t have any vets number I could call and I’ve been stressed for a month that something bad will happen to my cats.

**Is there anything I can do do treat the (suspected) fever of my cat without leaving the home?** Is there any home remedy or common medication I might have at home that I can give her?

Comment: Find the number of an emergency vet clinic in your area. Call them and ask what to do!

Comment: does it take a month for you to get help if you or your family is having a medical emergency? you do obviosly have an internet connection so get the number now and do the call.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: **NEVER give your cat medicine for humans!** Please read [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/726/12501) for more details. And I changed the question specifically to ask for home remedies that allow you to treat your at home.

Comment: It has been several days now since your question. Is the fever broken? As a human, I don't go to the vet the same day I have a fever, I usually wait at least for a day to see if it is transient, but if it still persists you have to get it to a vet.